# Applying substitution to $\int \sqrt{1+\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm having a problem with substituting when it comes to trig functions.

The integral is:$$\int\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}dx$$

Substituting: $1+\sin(x) = u \implies \frac{d}{dx} u = \cos(x) \implies dx = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}du$

So now we have the integral: $$\int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{\cos(x)}du$$

So now the question is, what do I do with the $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$? How can I substitute that with $u$?

Comment: Note $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)} = \sqrt{1 - (u-1)^2} $ as the general method. But maybe you find a nicer (similar) substitution ...

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2=\cos^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$

Comment: I wouldn't go for this substitution, but use the identity$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$to get back in terms of $u$

Comment: It is $$\cos(x)=\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint Write your integrand in the form
$$\sqrt{\frac{(1+\sin(x))(1-\sin(x))}{1- \sin(x)}}=\frac{\pm\cos(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}$$
and substitute $$t=1-\sin(x)$$ then we get $$dt=-\cos(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Here I give you an alternative approach. Observer that

\begin{align*}
1 + \sin(x) & = 1 + 2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) =  \left[\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]^{2}
\end{align*}

Hence the given integral is equal to

\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}\mathrm{d}x = \int\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin(x)}2}
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)}2}\\
&=\left|\,\cos\left(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac x2\right)\,\right|
\end{align}
$$